# PHP - Convert textarea submitted

Tags: php

I have bad characters like È™ that needs to be replaced. I have 99% of the code prepared but there's one thing I'm missing ... I don't know how to convert content from textarea, and then replace it with the good characters

to be more precise the below script works for displaying the text, what I need is to replace that text with the good version

```
// define variables and set to empty values
$comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <textarea class="comment" id="comment" name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";


$ToReplace = array("Äƒ", "Ã®", "È›", "ÅŸ", "Å£", "È™", "Ã¢", "ÃŽ", "î", "Î", "â", "ÇŽ", "“", "”", "Ã", "�");
$Replacement   = array("a", "i", "t", "s", "t", "s", "a", "i", "i", "I", "a", "a", "'", "'", "a", "a");
$convert = str_replace($ToReplace, $Replacement, $comment);

echo $convert;
```

Comment: instead of echo'ing $comment, echo $convert inside the text box.  To do that, move your convert code up so it occurs before the textbox.

Comment: You might want to do a key value pair for your ToReplace and Replacement array and then just use a foreach. Something like "Äƒ" = "a" would be the first value in your $Replacements array. Then foreach($Replacements as $replace => $with){str_replace($replace, $with, $comment);
}

Answer (score 0):

If I did understood your question **what you are aiming for is to replace the text inside the `textarea`**. If that's the case is simply a matter of ouputing your `$convert` variable inside the `textarea`.

As by your example this works:

```
// define variables and set to empty values
$comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }
}


$ToReplace = array("Äƒ", "Ã®", "È›", "ÅŸ", "Å£", "È™", "Ã¢", "ÃŽ", "î", "Î", "â", "ÇŽ", "“", "”", "Ã", "�");
$Replacement   = array("a", "i", "t", "s", "t", "s", "a", "i", "i", "I", "a", "a", "'", "'", "a", "a");
$convert = str_replace($ToReplace, $Replacement, $comment);



function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <textarea class="comment" id="comment" name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $convert;?></textarea>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $convert;
```

Comment: thank you, it woks ... a weird thing on the other hand is that it works for some of the characters but it won't work for the others ... am i missing some utf-8 or something ?

Comment: Lter Edit: i was missing utf-8 meta tag on html. everithing works great ... thank you for the help ... i tred giving rep pointss but it seems i'm not allowed to do so...

Comment: @ccc super! ;) Now on the spirit of SO (stackoverflow) if you believe the answer is correct you may upvote the answer and mark it as the solution.